# javascript bitwise and confusion

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation

Code like this:

```
let a = 3232237057
let b = 4294967040
let c = a & b
console.log(a.toString(2))
console.log(b.toString(2))
console.log(c.toString(2))
```

Output is:

```
11000000101010000000011000000001
11111111111111111111111100000000
-111111010101111111101000000000
```

I have expected output like:

```
11000000101010000000011000000001
11111111111111111111111100000000
11000000101010000000011000000000
```

What is wrong?

Comment: JS bitwise operations *only* work on 32-bit signed integers. If a number is larger than 32-bit (`2 ^ 31 - 1` or `2147483647`) the bitwise representation is truncated.

Comment: The easiest way to do it is with BigInt - change `a = BigInt(3232237057)` and `b = BigInt(4294967040)` then `c` would be `3232237056n` or `11000000101010000000011000000000` in binary.